# Boost Spirit Grammar To Detect Login Failure

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have written the following simple grammar to detect if a string returned by a server is a failed login. I was using it inlined in the `phrase_parse` function, but since the code gets called regularly, I wanted to make a static instance of the grammar. What I was using was this:

```
bool loginFailed() 
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    // current data is an re2 stringpiece. so .data returns char*
    const char* front = currentData.data();
    const char* back = currentData.end();

    return qi::phrase_parse(front, back, -qi::int_ >> (ascii::no_case[qi::lit("no")] | ascii::no_case[qi::lit("bad")]), qi::space);
}
```

Which works. However, when I translated this to the following, the grammar seems to always fail. What I would like to do is in my cpp file:

```
namespace {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    struct FailedGrammar : qi::grammar<const char*>
    {
        FailedGrammar() : 
            FailedGrammar::base_type(m_start),
            m_start()
        {
            m_start = -qi::int_ >> (ascii::no_case[qi::lit("no")] | ascii::no_case[qi::lit("bad")]);
        }
        qi::rule<const char*> m_start;
    };

    const FailedGrammar s_failedInstance;
}
```

and then call like this:

```
bool loginFailed() 
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    // current data is an re2 stringpiece. so .data returns char*
    const char* front = currentData.data();
    const char* back = currentData.end();

    return qi::phrase_parse(front, back, s_failedInstance, qi::space);
}
```

The string I am trying to recognize is something like this:

```
0002 NO FAILED LOGIN
```

where the numbers are optional. I am aware of other ways to do this with re2, however, I am looking for a spirit implementation.

Does anyone have any pointers or potential reasons this fails?

**Edit:**
I found quite a few issues with my grammar just poking around with the debugger. First, I realized to parse a number such as 0002 I should have wrote `*(qi::int_)`. Also, I got rid of the `ascii::space` in favor of the `ascii::blank`

Comment: "I realized to parse a number such as 0002 I should have wrote *(qi::int_)" - if the number is not optional, either use `qi::uint_` or `+qi::digit` or even `repeat(4)[digit]`

Comment: Good thinking on the blank. I was almost going to mention it, but I know nothing about your "grammar" and didn't want to complicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version uses a skipper.

Your second doesn't¹. You *could* fix it:

```
struct FailedGrammar : qi::grammar<const char*, qi::space_type>
{
    FailedGrammar() : FailedGrammar::base_type(m_start), m_start()
    {
        m_start = -qi::int_ >> (ascii::no_case[qi::lit("no")] | ascii::no_case[qi::lit("bad")]);
    }
    qi::rule<const char*, qi::space_type> m_start;
};
```

Note: Using qi::space/qi::lit and ascii::no_case is inconsistent. You can simplify greatly.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fd48d8899d654b0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

namespace login_detection {
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    static const rule<const char*> s_failed = skip(space) [ no_case [ -int_ >> lit("no") | "bad" ] ];
}

bool loginFailed2(boost::string_ref response) {
    return parse(response.begin(), response.end(), login_detection::s_failed);
}

int main() {
    return loginFailed2("0002 NO FAILED LOGIN")? 1 : 2;
}
```

In fact there's little or no reason to have the rule at namespace scope:

```
bool loginFailed2(boost::string_ref response) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    static const rule<const char*> s_failed = skip(space) [ no_case [ -int_ >> lit("no") | "bad" ] ];
    return parse(response.begin(), response.end(), s_failed);
}
```

I suggest comparing the generated assembly, though, because I think I will be ***identical*** to

```
bool loginFailed2(boost::string_ref response) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    return phrase_parse(response.begin(), response.end(), no_case [ -int_ >> lit("no") | "bad" ], space);
}
```

¹ [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

Comment: Great and very detailed answer! Thanks!